# The volume of the cylinder with its part cut out

Tags: calculus

[image: This is the image of the cylinder I am describing.]

As shown on the above image, I have a cylinder with its part cut out. The cylinder is cut out by the plane including three points(A, B, and C). The line BC is the diameter of the base circle and the point A is the midpoint of the semicircle as shown above. The plane divides the original cylinder into two parts, and I want to know the volume of the smaller part.

I calculated as follows.
First, I assumed that the radius of the base circle is r, and the height of the cylinder is h.
Then I figured out the area of the cut part at height z.
$$S(z) = 2 \int_{(\frac{r}{h})z}^{r} \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ dx $$
$$= r^{2}[cos^{-1}(\frac{z}{h}) - \frac{z}{h} \sqrt{1-(\frac{z}{h})^2}]$$
Finally, I integrated this area by the z-axis to earn the volume.
$$ V = \int_0^h S(z) dz$$
$$ = \frac{2}{3}r^2h $$

I am confused by this result because, at first(before I calculated the volume by integration) I thought the volume should be $ \frac{1}{4}\pi r^2h$, which is the quarter of the original cylinder. I thought so because the plane seemed to cut the exact half of the left side of the cylinder.

Please examine my calculation to check if I had made a mistake in the process of integration. Thank you.

Comment: I am confused by your cut. Can I solve in my way?

Comment: Sound intuition mon ami, sound intuition. The part gouged out does have that *one-fourthish* appearance. Sorry Henri Poincaire, you were, it seems, confusing $\frac{1}{4} \pi$ with $\frac{2}{3}$. Happens to everybody. By the way the ratio, good job, is $\approx 1$ (rounded to the nearest integer). I take back what I said about Poincare. You da man Poincare. Intuition rules!

Comment: By the way, is it $\frac{2}{3} r^2 h$ or $\frac{2}{3} \pi r^2 h$? The color indigo says, "are you mad?!"

Comment: Can we develop heuristics like this? We could call it *intuitive math*. Notice also that $\frac{2}{3} r^2 h\approx \frac{1}{5} \pi r^2 h$.

Comment: Are you comparing apples to oranges?

Comment: The picture is quite misleading. The half-ellipse on the tilted plane goes from $A$ to $C$ in the region $x<0$. It is far away from the point above $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume enclosed cannot be a quarter of the cylinder's total volume, because there is no symmetry that equates the desired volume with the part of the half-cylinder that lies above the planar cut.  As such, there is no reason to expect that these two volumes are equal.

The volume calculation can be performed by taking cross-sectional slices perpendicular to the $y$-axis, which will be rectangles of width $$W(y) = 2 \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$$ and height $$H(y) = h \frac{y}{r}.$$  Thus the differential volume of a representative slice for some $y \in [0,r]$ is
$$dV = W(y) H(y) \, dy = \frac{2hy}{r} \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \, dy.$$  The desired volume is therefore
$$V = \int_{y=0}^r dV = \frac{h}{r} \int_{y=0}^r 2y \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \, dy = \frac{h}{r} \left[-\frac{2}{3} (r^2 - y^2)^{3/2} \right]_{y=0}^r = \frac{2}{3} r^2 h.$$

It is an instructive exercise to compute the volume of the aforementioned region *above* the plane, which is given by the integral

$$V' = \int_{y=0}^r h\left( 1 - \frac{y}{r}\right) 2\sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \, dy.$$

Even without evaluating it, we can see that it cannot be equal to $V$.  Indeed,

$$V' = \int_{y=0}^r 2h \sqrt{r^2 - y^2} \, dy - V,$$

and the remaining integral term is simply the volume of half of the cylinder, with value $\frac{\pi}{2} r^2 h$.

As an exercise, how would you set up the volume integral for $V$ if you were to take cross-sectional slices perpendicular to the $x$-axis instead of the $y$-axis?  Instead of rectangles, what shape do the cross-sections have?

Comment: I think I can use triangular cross-sections perpendicular to the x-axis instead of the y-axis. Now I see that I didn't have to slice the figure perpendicular to the z-axis to integrate. It made the integration more complicated. Thank you for your responses!!

Answer (score 2):

You are genius. Your answer is correct. I didn't uderstand your way.:)

I will solve by ordinary caculus. The plane passing through $A=(0,-r,h)$, $B=(r,0,0)$, $C=(-r,0,0)$ is $z=-\frac hr y.$ The right projection of the solid, that you consider, on $xy$-plane is the region $\pi\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$, $0\leq r'\leq r$ in polar coordinates. Hence its volume is
$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\int_0^r\left(-\frac hr r'\sin\theta\right)r'dr'd\theta=\frac23 r^2h$$

Answer (score 2):

To understand why the volume of your given solid is less than expected, cut the cylinder with three planes:

Plane A:the given plane in the problem

Plane B: the plane you draw through the center, from the "top" of the Plane A cut to the antipodal point on the bottom edge

Plane C: Any horizontal plane passing through the interior of the cylinder.

Now look at the cross-section on Plane C. It is bounded by a circle from the cylinder's lateral surface and has two straight lines where Planes A and B intersect. Along the mirror line of this cross-section the segments from the cylinder surface to A and from A to B are indeed congruent. But otherwise the region between A and B is wider and bulging out more than the region on the other side of A that's in the volume you calculate. This inequality of cross-sections goes along with the problem's volume being less than a quarter of the cylindrr volume.

Comment: Another way to see that the volume above and below cannot be equal is to consider the family of generalized right cylinders with superelliptical cross-section of the form $$|x|^n + |y|^n = 1$$ for $n \in [1, \infty)$.  The case $n = 2$ is the circular cylinder in the original problem.  For $n = 1$, the enclosed region below the plane is a triangular pyramid with $1/3$ of the volume of the corresponding triangular prism.  As $n \to \infty$, the triangular prism becomes a rectangular prism and the volume approaches $1/2$ of this.  So the case $n=2$ will be somewhere in between.